# Overrided method visibility in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, visibility, protected

Assume that we have a package "p1":

```
package p1;

public class A {
    protected void method() { }
}
```

... and we also have a package "p2":

```
package p2;

import p1.A;

public class B extends A { }

class Tester {
    static void run() {
        new B().method(); //compile-time error
    }
}
```

Now if we try to compile a whole example we'll stuck at the marked line with compile-time error: compiler just doesn't see a target method in B. Why so?

Comment: Beacuse `method()` is `protected`?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [Access Modifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) for `A.method()` is `protected` and `B extends A`, there exists `protected B.method()` but it is to be noted that, for `protected method()` in class `B`, `method()` is like an "Private Entity" for class `B` and only "Public Entities" can be referenced from any object and thus `new B().method()` gives compile time error.

To make your code work, you can change the access modifier.

```
package p2;

import p1.A;

public class B extends A {

    @Override
    public void method() {
        super.method();
    }
 }
```

Comment: thanks, I've got your idea. Of course I know that if I mark overrided method as public - everyone and everywhere will be able to reference it. But still... I'm just trying to make some logic, let me explain:
1. protected methods are visible for subclasses and for classes inside the same package...
2. class B "IS-A" class A (because it extends one) - so I assume, that "B" also has the method (because "A" has it) and it's visibility can not be narrowed by overriding... 
So - if "B" has protected "method" - why it can not be accessed from the same package?

Comment: @IlyaGubarev make sense but the thing is `method()` is of class `A` which is in different package and thus can't be accessed by `Tester`.

Comment: @IlyaGubarev Try overriding `protected void method()` in `B` which simply calls `super.method()`, that may allow you to call `method()` from `Tester`.

Comment: ok, now I think that I've got it (the "method" is a part of "A", not "B", even if "B" IS-A "A"). Actually I've already made just an overrided protected version, just like you had commented before. Anyway it was more of theoretical problem for me - it is just a surprising behaviour of javac, though I really love Java inheritance rules. Thanks for interesting point of view.

Comment: Wow. This is super dumb. I come to the conclusion that package visibility is fundamentally flawed. (I noticed this, because I removed a "superflous" override and ran into the compile error...)

Answer (score 0):

Protected method is visible in all classes which *extends the base* (even in hierarchy) or within the *same package*. You are trying to use method in other package and in non-extending class.

Comment: but it's called from `Tester` class which do not extend `A` (or `B`)

Answer (score 0):

A protected method of a superclass, becomes private in the subclass.
If you really want to call it from anywhere then make it public OR ,if you still want to keep your superclass method protected, make a public method in the subclass that calls the (private, inherited) method, something in the subclass like:

```
public class B extends A { 
      public void callTheMethod(){
             method();
      }
}
```

and that can be easily called by test class with

```
class Tester {
    static void run() {
        new B().callTheMethod(); //works well
    }
}
```